# Exporting products and categories from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.7, import, export

I am trying to export the categories and products from magento 1.7.0.2 so that I can import them to another 1.9 installation. I've tried the following

**System -> Export ->Dataflow - profiles -> Export All Products -> run profile**

This gives an internal server error. I have noticed that sites hosted with this company have these errors all over the place.

**Plain export of all category and product tables from first magento database, import to new installation**

This resulted in foreign key constraint errors that I couldn't face

**Set up Apache virtualbox on vagrant, copied magento installation to run the first option locally**

I can't log in to the admin area. This seems a common problem, I have tried all the solutions but its still not working

**Set up nginx virtualbox on vagrant, copied magento installation to run the first option locally**

I could install the copy of magento and log in without any problems at all but when I run the "Export all products" I run into "504 gateway timeout" and all my efforts to increase execution time made no difference.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the database options. If you export alle database tables starting with `catalog` and you have no quotes and orders (empty tables `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_order`, it should work without foreign key problems. If you have different attributes, you should perhaps export the eav_* tables as well.

By the way, why not re-use the whole database from the old system? that's the cleanest way to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for that, @andreasvonstudnitz. I forget now how this was resolved...